# A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to display my layout.jsx on the browser but keep getting "A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `Routes` element, never rendered directly;" error I tried wrapping it in `Routes` but keep getting the error.

```
import React from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../sidebar/Sidebar';
import Routes from '../Routes';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            
            <Route render={(props) =>(
                <div className='layout'>
                    <Sidebar {...props} />
                    <div className="layout__content">
                        <div className="layout__content-main">
                            <Routes />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

            )
            } />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';
import Customers from '../pages/Customers';

const RRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/'  component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path='/customers' component={Customers}/>
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default RRoutes
```

```
import React from 'react'

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello Sidebar
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Comment: The `Route` component ***must*** be rendered by a `Routes` component. There is also no `render` prop on the `Route` component. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To have a sidebar menu for an administrator

Comment: That seems unrelated to the route issue you are asking about. I was referring to the overall goal of the component. What *exactly* are you trying to render? Are you just wanting to wrap some routes with the layout div and sidebar? What props is `Sidebar` expecting to receive? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of `react-router-dom` are you trying to use? The code is using v5 component APIs but the error is from a RRDv6 installation. You can check the installed version by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from the project directory.

Comment: v6 . is the one am using

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming the version you are trying to use. Can you update your question to include a more complete code example? What/where is `Layout` being rendered? What is *your* `Routes` component?

Comment: So is `RRoutes` all the routes your app is rendering?

Comment: yes that is what am trying

Comment: earlier the the Routes was Switch in the RRoutes.jsx and I changed it to routes and now the error am getting is :           No routes matched location "/"

Comment: Can you also add the `Sidebar` component code and share how this `Layout` component is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed quite a bit. There are no longer any `component` or `render` and `children` function props, they were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Additionally, all `Route` components ***must*** be rendered by a `Routes` component, the spiritual successor to the v5 `Switch` component that handles route matching and rendering.

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from '../sidebar/Sidebar';
import MyRoutes from '../Routes';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='layout'>
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="layout__content">
          <div className="layout__content-main">
            <MyRoutes />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';
import Customers from '../pages/Customers';

const MyRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path='/customers' element={<Customers />}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default MyRoutes;
```